# How to add parameter to HTTP header using Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache, http, http-headers, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to add "Accept-Encoding" parametr as "gzip,deflate" to my HTTP header using HttpClient. Code is given bellow. However I am getting bellow error with the response and unable to add the header parameter. Response doesn't contain the added header field

```
String url = "http://192.168.1.25:8380/ABCDService?wsdl";
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.addHeader( "Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate" );
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

**Error : Internal Server Error**

Comment: is gzip ON on server side?  : more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999606/enable-gzip-compression-with-nginx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a server configuration problem. 
Did you enable compression server side?

if you use jax-rs reasteasy replies with a compressed response if you have the headers set.

In other frameworks you might have to set it yourself. With @gzip or implementing a WriterInterceptor